# Java GUI development manually

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

I am trying to make a panel to have 4 items on top. these are a `JLabel`, `JTextField`, `JLabel` and `JTextField`.

In the center I need a `JTextArea` and to the left of it a `JList` that is scrollable.

On the bottom I need 3 buttons.

What would be the best layout manager for this and how should I go about it?

Would having just 3 columns be a good idea?

[image]

Heres what I have so far:

```
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JTextField IDLabel = new JLabel("ID: ");
        IDLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
        panel.add(IDLabel);

        JTextArea IDText = new JTextField(5);
        IDText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
        panel.add(IDText);

        JLabel TitleLabel = new JLabel("Title: ");
        TitleLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
        panel.add(TitleLabel);

        JTextField TitleText = new JTextField(10);
        TitleText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
        panel.add(TitleText);


        JList list = new JList(new String[]{"test1", "test22"});

                list.setFixedCellWidth(150);
                list.setFixedCellHeight(50);
                list.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,16));
                list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        panel.add(list);

        JTextArea BodyArea = new JTextArea();
        BodyArea.setSize(200, 200);
        BodyArea.setText("Test area");
        panel.add(BodyArea);
```

Comment: +1 for being the one righteous person to post a mock-up GUI of the intended result & code of "what I have done so far".

Answer (score 2):

You will mostly likely need to use a combination of layouts (AKA compound layouts), for example

**North Panel**

Create a `JPanel` and assign it a `FlowLayout` or `GridBagLayout` or `GridLayout` depending on what you want to achieve.

Add the `JLabel`, `JTextField`, `JLabel`, `JTextField` to it.

**Center Panel**

Create a `JPanel` with `BorderLayout`.  Add the `JTextArea` to the `CENTER` position and the `JList` to the `WEST` position

**South Panel**

Craete a `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout` or `GridBagLayout` or `GridLayout` depending on what you want to achieve.

Add the buttons to it.

**Putting it together**

Create a `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout`, add the "north" panel to the `NORTH` position, the "center" panel to the `CENTER` position and the "south" panel to the `SOUTH` position

You could use a single container and a `GridBagLayout`, but that's a lot of work.

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Maybe start with a `BorderLayout` for the main layout. Then you can add components to the PAGE_START (NORTH), LINE_START (WEST) and CENTER and PAGE_END (SOUTH). Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), for more information and examples.

Of course you would also use panels when you want to display multiple components in a single area. So your buttons would first be added to panels.

Also, follow standard naming conventions. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character( ie. BodyArea, TitleText). You got variable like (panel, list) correct so be consistent.